# Set ClientId in MC without using WSProxy?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I'm trying to impersonate ID of a subaccount without using WSProxy library but I can't find a way to do it.

In WSProxy we can do like this:

```
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
prox.setClientId({"ID": MID}) // Impersonation via WSProxy
```

The reason for this is that I feel like I can easily leverage Data Extension functions (E.g Rows.Retrieve)than the similar one in WSProxy.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Retrieve data from a DE hosted in a different BU? And why isn't using WSProxy an option if you're already using SSJS?

Comment: The context is I was trying to clone a data extension from a different BU (including the records in the DE). At first I used WSProxy and nested loops to do that due to the response JSON via WSProxy. Later I realized even I found a way to impersonate without using WSProxy (the purpose was I wouldn't use nested loops), I will face the limitation 2500 record results only with data extension functions. Eventually I ended up with the first approach